# Security Sign-in Mail using Firebase

Tags: firebase

How do I send a Security Sign-in mail to the users using firebase?

For example, your account was accessed at 3:21 pm, 16th Dec 2021.

Platform : Mac OS X, Chrome 96.0.4664

IP address: xxxxxxxxxxx

Location: xyz.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with an implementation.

I don't know if it is wise to execute this client-side (Can also be done using Cloud Functions).

```
authResult = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );

    final Map<String, dynamic> device = await getDeviceInfo();
    final Map<String, dynamic> net = await getNetworkInfo();
    final DateTime time = DateTime.now();

//I am using Trigger Email Extension here. 

    await mail.doc().set({
      'to': email.toLowerCase(),
      'message': {
        'subject': 'Succesful Login',
        'text':
            "Welcome back! You have successfully logged in to XYZ. You can now start using the app. Email = $email  Platform: ${device["name"]} Time: $time IP Address: ${net["wifiIP"]}",
      },
    });
```

These are the functions mentioned above:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getDeviceInfo() async {
  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    return iosInfo.toMap();
  } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidInfo.toMap();
  } else {
    WebBrowserInfo webBrowserInfo = await deviceInfo.webBrowserInfo;
    return webBrowserInfo.toMap();
  }
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getNetworkInfo() async {
  final info = NetworkInfo();

  var wifiName = await info.getWifiName(); // FooNetwork
  var wifiBSSID = await info.getWifiBSSID(); // 11:22:33:44:55:66
  var wifiIP = await info.getWifiIP(); // 192.168.1.43
  var wifiIPv6 =
      await info.getWifiIPv6(); // 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
  var wifiSubmask = await info.getWifiSubmask(); // 255.255.255.0
  var wifiBroadcast = await info.getWifiBroadcast(); // 192.168.1.255
  var wifiGateway = await info.getWifiGatewayIP(); // 192.168.1.1

  return {
    'wifiName': wifiName,
    'wifiBSSID': wifiBSSID,
    'wifiIP': wifiIP,
    'wifiIPv6': wifiIPv6,
    'wifiSubmask': wifiSubmask,
    'wifiBroadcast': wifiBroadcast,
    'wifiGateway': wifiGateway,
  };
}
```

[Trigger Email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have any feature built in for sending such sign-in alerts. It doesn't even have a way to build it on top of its existing providers, as there no server-side event when a user signs in.

The only option I can think of to implement this within Firebase is to [implement your own custom sign-in provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), and then send a message from there.

It also sounds like an interesting feature, so I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it.